# How to make sure at least one check box is selected

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to make sure at-least one check-box is selected using custom validator and javascript but but it does not show the error message at all. It blocks the code to go forward but fails to show the error message.  If I select one checkbox then the code move on to the next level.  What am missing here?  thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function ValidateModuleList(source, args) {
            var chkListModules = document.getElementById('<%= cblCustomerList.ClientID %>');
            var chkListinputs = chkListModules.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < chkListinputs.length; i++) {
                if (chkListinputs[i].checked) {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    </script>
```

and here is my custom validator and the control

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCustomerList" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
     DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupName" onclick="readCheckBoxList()">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>

 <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvmodulelist" ValidateModuleList"
      ErrorMessage="Please Select Atleast one Application" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Use a combobox. And I think you meant return true/false.

Comment: Are you catching the error at all?

Comment: it does not show the error at all.  when i hit the insert button it does not do anything in case i don't select anything.  I was expecting to see the error message that reads like " Please select atleast one application".  thanks

Comment: @moe - Try moving/commenting out your `return` statement and see if it fires then.

Comment: removed it but did not work..

Comment: You can debug your JavaScript code using the Developer Tools of your Browser, in most of them hitting F12 will bring them; there, there is a JavaScript debugger.

Comment: It sounds like a "style" problem... you might have a CSS style that is hiding the message. If you are using FireFox, try FireBug and see if the message is even been created/show or if a JavaScript error pops up in the console.

Comment: There's something wrong with the validator code you posted.  You have `ValidatorModuleList` just sitting there as an attribute rather than the value of an attribute.